# Arduino chip family

Tags: arduino-nano

This is a very basic question but I cannot find answer for this. I have a couple of Arduino Nano boards lying with me. With keen scrutinizing I found that a few chips on board where numbered as Atmega 328P-AU 1645 and some were numbered Atmega 328P-AU 1644. Can somebody please tell me the difference the number after AU makes ? I know the difference between an AU and PU chip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like a date code: YYWW, where YY are the last two digits of the year and WW is the ISO week number.

Comment: I hope it has got nothing to do with functionality and is only a sort of batch number.

Comment: They were made one week apart. That is the only difference.